# simple but difficult numpy memory reference problem

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
b = np.array([4,2,3])
c = np.array([5,5,2])

for i, e in enumerate(c):
    a[e] += b[i]
print(a)
# [0 0 3 0 0 6 0 0]

a = np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
b = np.array([4,2,3])
c = np.array([5,5,2])

a[c] += b[np.arange(len(b))]
print(a)
# [0 0 3 0 0 2 0 0]
```

The actual length of c is incredibly long. The problem comes from here.

The python for loop is too slow.

So I want to replace this with numpy without python for loop, but I can't find a way.

I think it's because of the memory reference.
Is there a way to change the result value of this to the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`np.add.at`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html#numpy.ufunc.at):

```py
cnt = np.arange(0, len(c))
np.add.at(a, c, b[cnt])

print(a)
```

Prints:

```
[0 0 3 0 0 6 0 0]
```

Comment: Simple and beautiful solution, exactly what I wanted. Thank you.